# Json JBuilder array from key value pairs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, jbuilder

In my current JSON output I have key value pair like this

```
"genres":[{"id":3,"name":"Biography"},{"id":1,"name":"Drama"},{"id":5,"name":"History"}]
```

and I want it to look like this.

```
"genres":["Biography", "Drama", "History"]
```

the closest I've gotten is this

```
"genres":[]
```

Seems relatively simple but I've tried a combination of things and I cannot get it to work. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: you should show your current jbuilder code

Comment: thank you, i accomplished what i needed with 
json.genres movie.genres.map { |g| g.name }